# SQL code for conversation messages like facebook

Tags: mysql, sql

tbl_messages:

```
m_from----m_to----m_message----m_date--------m_time
1000------1001----hello-------------2013-02-01----12:11:11
1001------1000-----hi----------------2013-02-01----13:10:11
1000------1001-----how r u?-------2013-02-01----16:19:11
1001------1000-----fine------------(2013-01-26)---12:11:11
1002------1003-----ur age?---------2013-03-10--13:14:11
1003------1002-----25----------------2013-03-11--13:36:15
1002------1000-----ur name?-------2013-02-04--13:52:44
1002------1000-----rihanna----------2013-05-15--13:11:54
1000------1002-----im there---------2013-02-01--13:34:11
1000------1003-----im here----------2013-02-01--13:04:00
```

For example user(1000)=Michael wants to see his messages.
Michael should only see users that send or receive message.

```
user(1000)=michael===messege send or receive====> user(1001)
user(1000)=michael===messege send or receive====> user(1002)
user(1000)=michael===messege send or receive====> user(1003)
```

I want SQL code that only users shows that Michael has a message exchange with them. The result be with last message (send or receive) ORDER BY (first) m_date (second) m_time

example: (this result is for user(1000))

```
user(1001)=david----------------------------------------------------time=16:19:11
send:slice of message(how r...)-----------------------------------date=2013-02-01user(1002)=jenifer----------------------------------------------------time=13:11:54
received:slice of message(rihanna...)----------------------------date=2013-05-15user(1002)=tom--------------------------------------------------------time=13:04:00
send:slice of message(im here...)----------------------------------date=2013-02-01
```

Comment: Have you tried a self-join?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing a table tbl_users with fields u_id and u_name.

Something along the lines of

```
(SELECT m_from, u_name, u_time, 'sent', m_message, m_date
FROM tbl_messsages inner join tbl_users on tbl_messages.m_from = tbl_users.u_id)
UNION
(SELECT m_to, u_name, u_time, 'received', m_message, m_date
FROM tbl_messsages inner join tbl_users on tbl_messages.m_to = tbl_users.u_id)
ORDER BY m_date, m_time;
```

Now, MySQL can do fancy things for formatting, but if I read your examples correctly, it can't put them like that, most likely, and you don't want to. A database (MySQL and others) is not made to do complex format transformation, but to store and retrieve information. The formatting can be done outside in another language.